# Customize-like form

Tags: customize, formatting, widget

I'd like to create a form, like the one displayed by customize, in order to ask to the user some information. The form should let me provide a description, a default value, and eventually display a choice list when needed.

The idea is that I don't want to use interactive prompt, firstly because the description can be really big, and also because most of the time the user just want to edit a tiny fraction of all the available options.

Any idea?

Comment: The question is too broad/vague. You don't even say how what you want is different from what Customize already provides. Consider showing what you've tried so far, and showing how Customize doesn't do the job.

Comment: Had you have a look at widgets: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html ?

Comment: @Drew : Well I don't want to use Customize, because I want to create my own form, for my own applications. But I'd like to understand how Customize was programmed in elisp.

Comment: @wvxvw: it's exactly was I need, thank you very much! Would you like to add the answer so that I can accept it?